# How to read and send data to PS/2 port?

Tags: windows, terminal, putty, monitoring, ps2

I have a device connected via PS/2 on Windows PC, acting like a keyboard. I would like to use a "terminal" to monitor the data coming from that port, and even send data to it.

I expected that was easy to find on the web (something like serial port monitors, or Putty...) but seems not. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at this open-source project
[Saleae PS/2 Keyboard Analyzer](https://github.com/saleae/ps2-keyboard-analyzer),
available for MacOS, Ubuntu/Linux and Windows.

There exist also hardware trace devices, but this is out of my scope.

Comment: It seems to be a library instead of a stand alone program, but thanks for now. 
I confirm I'm not looking for hardware analyzers

Comment: AFAICT that library merely decodes data captured from a logic analyser, rather than reading it from the computer's own PS/2 port.